# How do I open several FORTRAN files in Vim and save them as HTML files?

Tags: filetype-html, filetype-fortran

I know the separate answers. For example,

- To open several files: `:n \**/*.f90`
- To save `*.f90` file to HTML: `:TOhtml` and `:wq`.

However, I don't know how to combine both of them.

Comment: Do you have a plugin which has a command or function like `,Tohtml`?

Comment: `TOhtml` is built into Vim.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After you've added your files to the arguments list with `:n ./**/*.f90` (`:args` + filenames would do the same thing and is perhaps more obvious) you can use:

```
:argdo exe 'TOhtml' | wq
```

`:argdo` will execute its following commands for each buffer that's in the argument list. Note that you need to use `TOhtml` with `:execute` since it isn't defined to allow a following `|`. Using `:execute` allows you to work around this.

You may wish to modify the `:w` command to write the generated HTML buffer into another directory (e.g. `w html/%`). And it's probably a good idea to close each generated window as you go with `:q` so Vim doesn't run out of room for windows if you have lots of files to process.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can we restore the colors of the vim in the html files?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the following combined command:

```
:args ./**/*.f90 | argdo execute TOhtml
```

First, use `args` to fill the argument list, then use `argdo` to execute the `TOhtml` command. There should be no reason to `wq`, since there is no change to the files, thus I would instead do e.g. `:qa` when you were finished and happy.

Comment: The generated file needs writing both because, well, it does, and also because `:next` will fail if you don't have `autowrite` set. And if your argument list is large you might run out of room for windows, so it's a good idea to `:q` as well as `:w`.

Comment: Ah, you are right. I didn't look well enough into what `TOhtml` did. I think you could improve your answer if you included my first `:args ...` command, though.

Comment: The OP did that already so I presumed it was unnecessary, but it's definitely worth mentioning that up front since using `:args` first is quite important; thanks! (I respond eventually :-) )

Answer (score 2):

As pointed by "Karl Yngve Lervåg" in his comments, combining the answers of both "Karl Yngve Lervåg" and "Antony" gave me the desired result.

So, after opening the first .f90 file, you should use the below command

```
:args ./**/*.f90 | argdo exe 'TOhtml' | wq
```

The only trouble which I am still facing with the above method is: generated html files doesn't have colors of vim (except for the first .f90 file).